# Why or how did Durin the Deathless live so long?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, dwarves

Do we have any indication on why Durin I (the Deathless) was able to live such a long life? Sources [1,2] seem to indicate that he lived to be at least 2,395 years old.

Given that that is around ten times longer than the normal lifespan of a d surely there must have been some additional influence?

[1] [How long did Durin the Deathless live?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138914/how-long-did-durin-the-deathless-live)

[2] [Durin - Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin)

Comment: Instead of "sources say" you might want to specify exactly how you deduce your conclusion, based on the sources. That way, we can determine whether the sources do say that, or whether there's a misinterpretation or ambiguity somewhere.

Comment: There is no reason, he is just a legend as far as we're concerned, his story passed down by name rather than written by scholars and confirmed.

Comment: Because he was deathless. Duh.

Comment: Keep in mind that Durin's death in the "First Age" here is ambiguous.  Tolkien was not consistent about that terminology.  Sometimes he indicated the First Age of the Sun, which came after the Years of Trees, and sometimes "First Age" was a general term for the entire elder days before the overthrow of Morgoth.

Comment: @ibid That's what I opened the question to say; only that I wasn't going to add 'Duh.' But I'll add that being mortal he wasn't actually deathless so there has to be something - or some things - rather tricksy and false about his name.

Comment: I speculate that, as he was one of the original dwarves crafted by Aulë, and Aulë wasn't quite clear on the specifics of the Children, he kind of mashed Elves and Men together, not wanting his creations to wear out, yet also wanting to give them the gift of Death. So Durin got what Aulë considered the best of everything, as far as he could see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### We don't know

Rather than provide details on Durin I (aside from inclusion in the creation of the dwarves), Tolkien seems to have included him as more as a legend.

> Durin is the name that the Dwarves used for the eldest of the Seven Fathers of their race, and the ancestor of all the kings of the Long-beards. He slept alone, until in the deeps of time and the awakening of that people he came to Azanulbizar, and in the caves above Kheled-zâram in the east of the Misty Mountains he made his dwelling, where afterwards were the Mines of Moria renowned in song.
>
> There he lived so long that he was known far and wide as Durin the Deathless. Yet in the end he died before the Elder Days had passed, and his tomb was in Khazad-dûm; but his line never failed, and five times an heir was born in his House so like to his Forefather that he received the name of Durin.
> <sub>*Appendix A - III: Durin's Folk*</sub>

We have no information to suggest a reason for his longevity. We simply know that he was "born" before 1250 Y.T. and died before the end of the First Age (which was roughly 19,000 adjusted years later).

Comment: Or rather, he was forged by Aulë along with the other first dwarves  _well before_ (an indeterminate amount of time) the Two Trees came up, and was awake for a little while, until Ilúvatar chastized Aulë, who put them to sleep again until some indeterminate time after the Elves first awoke.

Comment: I think in regards to Middle Earth history, his "birth" is supposed to be the date of his post-elf awakening. But yes, you are correct.